# Bulk import wordpress users with pre-hashed passwords

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm migrating a whole slew of users between two self-hosted Wordpress sites, and I'm trying to find a way to bring them across without resetting their passwords. The current site has everyone's passwords, naturally, all nicely hashed. Currently the two methods I could see to import these users ([wp_insert_user()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) and [wp_create_user()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user)) both require the passwords to be in clear text. Is there something I'm missing, or can this just not be done with current methods?

Comment: The dedicated free [Wordpress user import export](https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/) plugin will do this and keep the same password across

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 options. Run a custom database query, copy and modify `wp_insert_user()`, or run `wp_insert_user()` twice.

**Copy and modify `wp_insert_user()`**

Below is a custom `wp_insert_user` function. All I've done is removed the line that hashes the PW.

```
function wpse_custom_insert_user( $userdata ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( is_a( $userdata, 'stdClass' ) )
        $userdata = get_object_vars( $userdata );
    elseif ( is_a( $userdata, 'WP_User' ) )
        $userdata = $userdata->to_array();

    extract( $userdata, EXTR_SKIP );

    // Are we updating or creating?
    if ( !empty($ID) ) {
        $ID = (int) $ID;
        $update = true;
        $old_user_data = WP_User::get_data_by( 'id', $ID );
    } else {
        $update = false;
    }

    $user_login = sanitize_user($user_login, true);
    $user_login = apply_filters('pre_user_login', $user_login);

    //Remove any non-printable chars from the login string to see if we have ended up with an empty username
    $user_login = trim($user_login);

    if ( empty($user_login) )
        return new WP_Error('empty_user_login', __('Cannot create a user with an empty login name.') );

    if ( !$update && username_exists( $user_login ) )
        return new WP_Error( 'existing_user_login', __( 'Sorry, that username already exists!' ) );

    if ( empty($user_nicename) )
        $user_nicename = sanitize_title( $user_login );
    $user_nicename = apply_filters('pre_user_nicename', $user_nicename);

    if ( empty($user_url) )
        $user_url = '';
    $user_url = apply_filters('pre_user_url', $user_url);

    if ( empty($user_email) )
        $user_email = '';
    $user_email = apply_filters('pre_user_email', $user_email);

    if ( !$update && ! defined( 'WP_IMPORTING' ) && email_exists($user_email) )
        return new WP_Error( 'existing_user_email', __( 'Sorry, that email address is already used!' ) );

    if ( empty($nickname) )
        $nickname = $user_login;
    $nickname = apply_filters('pre_user_nickname', $nickname);

    if ( empty($first_name) )
        $first_name = '';
    $first_name = apply_filters('pre_user_first_name', $first_name);

    if ( empty($last_name) )
        $last_name = '';
    $last_name = apply_filters('pre_user_last_name', $last_name);

    if ( empty( $display_name ) ) {
        if ( $update )
            $display_name = $user_login;
        elseif ( $first_name && $last_name )
            /* translators: 1: first name, 2: last name */
            $display_name = sprintf( _x( '%1$s %2$s', 'Display name based on first name and last name' ), $first_name, $last_name );
        elseif ( $first_name )
            $display_name = $first_name;
        elseif ( $last_name )
            $display_name = $last_name;
        else
            $display_name = $user_login;
    }
    $display_name = apply_filters( 'pre_user_display_name', $display_name );

    if ( empty($description) )
        $description = '';
    $description = apply_filters('pre_user_description', $description);

    if ( empty($rich_editing) )
        $rich_editing = 'true';

    if ( empty($comment_shortcuts) )
        $comment_shortcuts = 'false';

    if ( empty($admin_color) )
        $admin_color = 'fresh';
    $admin_color = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9 _.\-@]|i', '', $admin_color);

    if ( empty($use_ssl) )
        $use_ssl = 0;

    if ( empty($user_registered) )
        $user_registered = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    if ( empty($show_admin_bar_front) )
        $show_admin_bar_front = 'true';

    $user_nicename_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_nicename = %s AND user_login != %s LIMIT 1" , $user_nicename, $user_login));

    if ( $user_nicename_check ) {
        $suffix = 2;
        while ($user_nicename_check) {
            $alt_user_nicename = $user_nicename . "-$suffix";
            $user_nicename_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_nicename = %s AND user_login != %s LIMIT 1" , $alt_user_nicename, $user_login));
            $suffix++;
        }
        $user_nicename = $alt_user_nicename;
    }

    $data = compact( 'user_pass', 'user_email', 'user_url', 'user_nicename', 'display_name', 'user_registered' );
    $data = wp_unslash( $data );

    if ( $update ) {
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->users, $data, compact( 'ID' ) );
        $user_id = (int) $ID;
    } else {
        $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->users, $data + compact( 'user_login' ) );
        $user_id = (int) $wpdb->insert_id;
    }

    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

    foreach ( _get_additional_user_keys( $user ) as $key ) {
        if ( isset( $$key ) )
            update_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $$key );
    }

    if ( isset($role) )
        $user->set_role($role);
    elseif ( !$update )
        $user->set_role(get_option('default_role'));

    wp_cache_delete($user_id, 'users');
    wp_cache_delete($user_login, 'userlogins');

    if ( $update )
        do_action('profile_update', $user_id, $old_user_data);
    else
        do_action('user_register', $user_id);

    return $user_id;
}
```

**Running `wp_insert_user` twice**

If you run `wp_insert_user()` `user_pass` is expected to be a plain string. If you include an ID parameter however you need to use a hashed password instead.

You could run `wp_insert_user()` with a random password to insert the user. This will return an ID. You could then run the same function again including the ID and the hashed password.

As I pointed out above this is inefficient and not something I'd suggest but it would be possible. Here's an example:

```
$hashed_pw = get_hashed_pw(); // Replace this with the correct hashed password.

$user_args = array(
    'ALL MY' => 'OTHER ARGS', // Enter all your other arguments for wp_insert_user().
    'user_pass' => 'random', // Set this to a random string.
);

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $user_args );

$update_user_args = array(
    'ID' => $user_id,
    'user_pass' => $hashed_pw,
);

wp_insert_user( $update_user_args );
```

This is not a complete solution. If you were to use it you'd want to include some error checking, etc. You're much better off with one of the two other solutions posed.